# How to hide firebase api key

Tags: firebase, github

I have done a project with firebase. Now if I want to push this code on github how can I secure my firebase API keys.

Comment: There is a lot of existing conversation on API keys, security and source control on Stack Overflow.  If you have a more specific question after reading all that, please post again with better details.